# Differences between ros_control and arbotix driver package

Tags: control, gazebo, simulation, ros-control, arbotix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

1, I wonder what are the differences or similarities between ros_control and arbotix driver.

2, Does **arbotix driver** belong to firmware for harware ? In other words, it belongs to **hardware_interface:RobotHW** ?

3, **ros_control** covers the **controller_manager** and **harware resource interface layer** ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260530/differences-between-ros_control-and-arbotix-driver-package/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ros_control is a generic robot controller package, whereas arbotix_driver is a package designed for a specific hardware device.

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-04-29**:
Thanks for your quick reply.
I wonder why in book, ros by example volume 2, it never mentions ros_control, but uses arbotix package instead, it completes the motion planning and execution along with moveit. It seems like arbotix completes the jobs including controller manager and hardware_interface

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-05-02**:
I have not read the book, but there are many reason why a book would not include a specific ros package. (Publication date, specific robot packages etc)

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-05-03**:
I check arbotix package, I notice that

```
The arbotix_python package also offers several controllers which add higher-level interfaces to common hardware
```

Does it mean arbotix package cover the functionalities of ros_control?
[Link to arbotix_python](http://wiki.ros.org/arbotix_python)

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-05-03**:
From a quick look to the source code, arbotix_python seems to be independent of ros _control, and does not seem to implement the hardware_interface interface. Thus, it should be used only with very specific hardware.